# How do I add textboxes and drop downs to FancyTree

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I want to add a textbox and drop down menu to my FancyTree implementation using the generateFormElements function.  Is this possible and if so, can someone point me to an example of how it's implemented?  From what I can see, it seems to only apply to checkboxes and radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generateFormElements` is only used to render hidden form elements that reflect the tree's selection state and then can be sent using a standard form submit. Therefore only checkbox items are created. It would make no sense to render text boxes or dropdowns here.

If you want to create those elements in a tree, you can pass html as a node title ([example](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/index.html#sample-multiline.html)).
If you want to render it in a tree grid, use `renderColumns` ([example](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/index.html#sample-multi-ext.html)).

Comment: Thanks mar 10.  That's kind of what I did.  I will post my code here later today.

Comment: How to you retrieve the value of the form elements, say a text input, if the node is hidden. So the user edits the value, hides the node, and then I need to get the value from it?